# How to append a link label to an existing label?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a label inside a panel to display simple text. Now I have a link label that is added dynamically that displays some more information. How can I show this link label right next to the label text at run time? For example, the lable displays

A record is added.

I need to show with a link label "View Additional Details" next to the label text.

A record is added.  View Additional Details

I have the code as below but it overlaps the existing label text. Thanks for any help!

```
        LinkLabel details = new LinkLabel();
        details.Text = "View Additional Details";

        LinkLabel.Link link = new LinkLabel.Link();
        link.LinkData = infoDetails;

        details.Links.Add(link);

        details.LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(details_LinkClicked);
        //Adding the link label control to the existing label control
        lblInfo.Visible = true;
        lblInfo.AutoSize = true;
        lblInfo.Controls.Add(details);
```

Comment: Do you add control in the `panel`? Apparently it seems you are specifying `label` instead.

Comment: On the last line. what is variable `detailsLinks`? Did you mean to put `lblInfo.Controls.Add(details)` there?

Comment: The label is already added to the panel. May be I need to add the link label too to the panel and not the label.

Comment: Sorry, I modified the last line now.

Comment: @Jyina - or you can add both labels dynamically (both "A record is added." and "View Additional Details"). But you still would need to fight lable size issue. I would go with adding empty LinkLabel and updating it in runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to add a LinkLabel to a label? Add the LinkLabel to the same form as the label, and set the location of the LinkLabel appropriately.

In the example below, I'm assuming the code is being called from the form's class (or to a panel if you are using one). If not, replace `this` with your form instance. I'm setting the Y location as the same as `lblInfo` so the LinkLabel appears next to it. Adjust `lblInfo.Margin.Right` and `details.Margin.Left` as desired.

```
details.Margin.Left = 5;
details.Location = new Point(
     lblInfo.Location.X + lblInfo.Width + lblInfo.Margin.Right + details.Margin.Left,
     lblInfo.Location.Y
 );
this.Controls.Add(details);
```

Update: changed padding to use Margin (thanks Anthony).

Comment: Instead of the padding variable, use the margins associated with the controls: `lbleInfo.Location.X + lbleInfo.Margin.Right + details.Margin.Left`.